# Page will not scroll when cursor gets to the bottom of page; does not keep text at eye level

Tags: microsoft-word

Since having to get rid of Windows XP, I am using Windows 7 Professional, MS Word 2013, and Logitech HID-compliant mouse model M510.

Since using Word 2013, when the cursor gets to the bottom of the page while typing, the lines start scrolling one line at a time and the cursor stays on that bottom line.  It never jumps the text to the middle of the screen to eye level.  In all my years of using Word and prior to that Word Perfect, I have never encountered this.  I have found several users having the same issues since using Word 2013 but no fix for the issue.  In other words, the text will not scroll properly and maintain an eye level for ease of typing.  I do not know if this is a Windows problem but think it is a Word problem.  Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem I had.
Solution is

1. Create a new user account, type : `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Templates` in explorer,
   copy the normal.doc file and paste it in different temporary drive E.
2. come  back to the current user in explorer of different temporary drive E.
3. copy the type : Normal.doc
4. open the explorer, type `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Template` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ( File Normal.Doc)

Wow cursor starts from top of text area.
Basically you're copying a new Word template from different user and pasting it in this Word template.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).